# Mysql field with separated values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a report to pull out entries from a form.  The form looks like this:
[Form Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iusYD.png)

I found the table that contains this data, and the row for the question on the form looks like this

```
id,evaluation,template,name,label,presentation,typ,hasvalue,position,required,dependitem,dependvalue,options,grade,correctanswer
286,20,0,"Perform equipment test",,"r>>>>>5
|4
|3
|2
|1
|NA",radiobuttonselection,1,24,1,0,,h,0,
```

The field "presentation" I want to draw your attention to.  The value in this field is:

```
"r>>>>>5
|4
|3
|2
|1
|NA"
```

That is just one value stored in a column in the row.

I also found the table that stores the form responses.  It has a integer column named "value" that, in this case, will contain a value from 1 to 6.  A 1 represents the first item in the "presentation" column, a 5.  A 6 represents N/A.

How can I write my select to convert the 1-6 value for the form response, to the descriptive value in the "presentation" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have a built-in function to split strings, but you can create one like so:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SPLIT_STRING;
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(delim VARCHAR(3), str VARCHAR(255), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN
    REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1
        ),
        delim, ''
    );
```

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get the answer from the lookup table in your query. I assume they're best in individual columns. In the code below, I'm only transposing two answers, but you can proceed with all of them in a similar manner.

```
with mod_form_data as
(SELECT *, right(SPLIT_STRING('|', presentation, 1),1) first,
  SPLIT_STRING('|', presentation, 2) second
from form_data)
select id, (select answer from answers where id = mfd.first),
(select answer from answers where id = mfd.second) 
from mod_form_data mfd
```

I tested this with your data recreated as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE form_data (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `evaluation` INTEGER,
  `template` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(24),
  `label` varchar(2),
  `presentation` VARCHAR(20),
  `typ` VARCHAR(20),
  `hasvalue` INTEGER,
  `position` INTEGER,
  `required` INTEGER,
  `dependitem` INTEGER,
  `dependvalue` varchar(100),
  `options` VARCHAR(1),
  `grade` INTEGER,
  `correctanswer` varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO form_data
  (`id`, `evaluation`, `template`, `name`, `label`, `presentation`, `typ`, `hasvalue`, `position`, `required`, `dependitem`, `dependvalue`, `options`, `grade`, `correctanswer`)
VALUES
  ('286', '20', '0', 'Perform equipment test', '', 'r>>>>>5|4|3|2|1|NA', 'radiobuttonselection', '1', '24', '1', '0', '', 'h', '0', '');
       

          
create table answers (id integer, answer varchar(255));                                                   
insert into answers values (5, 'One answer');
insert into answers values (4, 'Another answer');
```

Comment: I think this works except where pos = 1, it returns 'r>>>>>5' instead of 5, but I think I see how I can modify it to work for pos = 1.  Thanks!

Comment: If it works for you, please upvote and accept the answer. As stated in my post, I didn’t go through every part of the split string. The first one shows how you can use substring as well.